# How to wrap text in tkinter entry field

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How would I wrap text in the entry field in `Tkinter` on this box and make the text entered start from the top and make the entry field taller so it fits the whole gray box.

Image of the text box:

[image: image of the text box]

```
# This file was generated by the Tkinter Designer by Parth Jadhav
# https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer


from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage


OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"assets\new_post_page")


def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)


window = Tk()

window.geometry("418x419")
window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")


canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 419,
    width = 418,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
image_1 = canvas.create_image(
    209.0,
    38.0,
    image=image_image_1
)

entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_1.png"))
entry_bg_1 = canvas.create_image(
    209.5,
    225.5,
    image=entry_image_1
)
entry_1 = Entry(
    bd=0,
    bg="#D9D9D9",
    fg="#000716",
    highlightthickness=0

)
entry_1.place(
    x=26.0,
    y=99.0,
    width=367,
    height=251
)

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
button_1 = Button(
    image=button_image_1,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
)
button_1.place(
    x=10.0,
    y=364.0,
    width=94.0,
    height=41.0
)

image_image_2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_2.png"))
image_2 = canvas.create_image(
    369.0,
    38.0,
    image=image_image_2
)
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

I have tried to search elsewhere however it only gives me answers on how to wrap it for a Label, and I also couldnt find anyway way on making the entry taller or start from the top

Comment: You *can't* wrap text in an Entry, because it only supports a single line of text.  You'd have to change to a Text widget instead (but note that the methods for getting/setting the content of a Text are entirely different from an Entry).

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap text in an `Entry` field. It is designed to hold a single line of information.

If you need the text to wrap then you will need to use a `Text` widget instead, and turn wrapping on with the `wrap` attribute. You can set it to either `"word"` or `"char"` to wrap at word or character boundaries respectively.